# code sample or tutorial on building an add-on to internet explorer that records the sites visited?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer

Looked to build an add-on for IE that records the websites visited by the user.  Can't seem to find any code or samples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of IE add-on sample code projects out there.  Use teh Googles.

Look for one that implements DWebBrowserEvents2.  Use the OnBeforeNavigate and OnDocumentComplete events.

Answer (score 1):

You mean to reproduce the History function?